# How can "Shazam" say his name without changing?

Tags: plot-explanation, dc-extended-universe, shazam

I haven't seen the movie, but I remember the old Captain Marvel, and when other kids called him "Shazam" I corrected them.

I would point out how silly it would be if someone you rescued asked who you were, and when you told them your name you changed into your other form.

Now DC are calling him "Shazam" both in comics and movies. Have they addressed this issue, and if so, how?

Comment: Related (on [scifi.se]): https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/64521/how-does-shazam-tell-people-his-name

Comment: His name is Captain Sparkle fingers!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**In comics:**

[CBR](https://www.cbr.com/shazam-billy-batson-name/2/) covered it very well with a comic book panel

[image]

> Billy has to say it while giving the word MEANING for it to work as a magic word...

So he can get around with it and say it without transforming in comics but lately, he is having an issue with it:

[image]

**From movies:**

In movies, he never called himself Shazam as a name but only for transformation. And he said the name Shazam in front of the wizard so casually and still transformed and even with Darla it happen and it seems like an issue. Rest we have to see it in future films, how they deal with it.

Comment: This matches up with the 70s Saturday morning TV show I watched as a kid, which apparently respected the comics more than I thought.  (The added reverb helped, too.)

Comment: @JBH added reverb was from old comcis I guess